# How to reference a parameter as a variable in Jenkins Groovy Script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

When trying to use a parameter reference in another parameter in Jenkins Groovy Script, it does not return the value. It remains as ${variable} , What am I doing wrong?

InstanceType is a Active Choices Reactive Parameter

```
<select name ="value">
<option value ="Same_Value">${InstanceType}</option>
</select>
'''
html3 = '''
 <select name ="value">
 <option value ="t2.medium">t2.medium</option>
 <option value ="t2.large">t2.large</option>
 <option value ="t2.xlarge">t2.xlarge</option>
 <option value ="t2.2xlarge">t2.2xlarge</option>
 <option value ="t3.medium">t3.medium</option>
 <option value ="t3.large">t3.large</option>
 <option value ="t3.xlarge">t3.xlarge</option>
 <option value ="t3.2xlarge">t3.2xlarge</option>
</select>
 '''

if (MakeChanges.contains("yes")) {
     return html3 }
else { return html }
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is 2 fold:

1: Ensure that the referenced parameter is listed in the referenced parameters box

2: Ensure you are using triple double quote not triple single quote